# Android - Unable to resolve superclass

Tags: android, eclipse

I have dug out an old android project that I was working on a few years ago and loaded it into a new eclipse install (latest ADT etc).

The project all compiles ok (after some minor tweaking), and the app starts fine, however, when i press a button to start the main activity i get the following stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.tmm.android.activities.GameActivity
    at com.tmm.android.activities.StartActivity.onClick(StartActivity.java:53)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
```

Now the class in question (GameActivity) is one of my classes that is in the app, so I know thats not the problem - but I noticed a warning right at the top of the logcat:

```
Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/tmm/android/activities/GameActivity; (33)
Link of class 'Lcom/tmm/android/activities/GameActivity;' failed
```

My class GameActivity extends another class that is part of a third-party jar that i have included in the project (included it in the 'libs' directory, and added it to the project build path in eclipse).

Can anyone advise what I might have done wrong, or anything that has changed in the ADT/etc that I might need to take account of (it was working fine when i last had it in Eclipse)

Cheers

Comment: Sounds like there is a dependency that the superclass is relying on that is not installed.

Comment: that did cross my mind, but it is the same jar as I used last time I started up the app, so seems strange that it would be different - unless the android libraries have been changed?  Is there any easy way to debug what exactly is missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, was a simple problem in the end..

Having added the 3rd party library to the build path, the export tab wasnt defaulted to export the jar (eclipse normal behaviour) - so the jar wasnt being included in the deployment..

got past that problem ok..

Comment: I had to also put the 3rd party library at the top of my export list

Answer (score 29):

I had the same problem. I had a custom View class which called methods in an imported library.
I was also getting the "Unable to resolve superclass" error when the app was trying to create my view (while trying to inflate a layout that referred to that custom View).

I resolved my problem, and I had a play around to determine what I think is the definitive answer.

(As at writing, I am using the Eclipse Android Tools R21).

**If you are using an external jar**

- Copy it to your project's "libs" folder. The Android Tools should do the rest.

**If the library you want to use is a separate project in your workspace.**

- In your library project: go into Properties->Android and check the "Is Library" checkbox.
- In your app project: go into to Properties->Android and add the library project in the same section there (click "Add.."). Don't check "Is Library" here!

Some answers to this question say you need to go to Properties->Java Build Path->Projects and add the library project there. For normal Java projects you would do that, but it appears the Android Tools don't need or use that.

**Finally, you will probably want to make sure the lib is included in your exported app**

- Go to Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export and make sure the library is checked.

Comment: OMG A MILLION UPVOTES TO YOU SIR!!! Add Library... *facepalm. Normal Add project doesn't work for some strange reason.

Comment: Most important part is 
Go to Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export and make sure the library is checked.

Previously it was not required, seems from Tools R21 or R22 onwards its needed

Comment: Thank you. Run into annoying bug which cost me 10hours of work: support library was referenced from another project, on compile time everything was fine, but on runtime, the MainActivity wasn't found (Mainactivity was extended from a class in support library).

Comment: Thanks for solving a problem I had been struggling with for hours. Adding the library project via `Properties > Android > Library > Add` did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I tried to check the Android Private Libraries under Order and Export and it didn't work for me. So then I noticed that my libs folder wasn't referenced under the Java Build Path, I just added it to Libraries and that is it...